# selenium random id random xpath and random css selector

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

hi i'am beginner in selenium with python.. and the problem is the id, xpath, and css selector contain random id.. and i cant solve this problem because of the random id everytime i jumpin to the page 
I already try using xpath, id ,css selector even class name but didn't work. Hope anyone can help me and sorry for the bad grammar

```
<div role="option" id="listitem1innerListBoxjqxWidgetac7737dcf714" class="jqx-listitem-element" style="height: 24px; top: 25px; left: 0px;" aria-selected="true"><span style="white-space: pre; display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 193px;" class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-listitem-state-normal-default jqx-item jqx-item-default jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-default jqx-listitem-state-selected jqx-listitem-state-selected-default jqx-fill-state-pressed jqx-fill-state-pressed-default">0900</span></div>
<span style="white-space: pre; display: block; visibility: inherit; width: 193px;" class="jqx-listitem-state-normal jqx-listitem-state-normal-default jqx-item jqx-item-default jqx-rc-all jqx-rc-all-default jqx-listitem-state-selected jqx-listitem-state-selected-default jqx-fill-state-pressed jqx-fill-state-pressed-default">0900</span>

//*[@id="listitem1innerListBoxjqxWidgetac7737dcf714"]/span   <----Xpath
#listitem1innerListBoxjqxWidgetac7737dcf714 > span          <---css selector
```

there have random id everytime i go to the page. Hope anyone can solve my problem tq

Comment: Please post details on what you have tried

Comment: hour_click = context.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='listitem1innerListBoxjqxWidgetac7737dcf714']/span")
    hour_click.click()
    time.sleep(3)

Comment: hour_click = context.browser.find_element_by_id("listitem1innerListBoxjqxWidgetac7737dcf714")
    hour_click.click()
    time.sleep(3)

Comment: Is the class attribute of the div element the same (and unique enough) for every run? If so, modify the xpath to use the class attribute instead @class="jqx-listitem-element".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you have provided and your code trial to locate the element you can use either of the locator strategy :

- `css_selector` :

  ```
  context.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.jqx-listitem-element[id^='listitem1innerListBox'] > span")
  ```
- `xpath` :

  ```
  context.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='jqx-listitem-element' and starts-with(@id,'listitem1innerListBox')]/span")
  ```

Comment: thank you sir for helping me, right now i can figure out if the element have random id

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial id `listitem1innerListBox`

```
context.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'listitem1innerListBox')]/span") 

context.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[id*='listitem1innerListBox'] > span")
```